# Arrange view with multiple subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I did it on `Android`. Now I want to do it in `iOS`. As a beginner, I am confused what `iOS` developers may use for this. A `UITableView` or `UIStackView` or something else?

Please keep in mind:

- The box showing question number shouldn't change it's ratio
- The question text maybe 1 line, maybe 10 lines
- Options under the question maybe more or less than this
- The next and previous buttons should be at the end of all contents, not floating at bottom of the display

Comment: Is this universal app meaning you are targetting all iOS devices? Then auto layout will probably be your best bet(Any Any size).
Great guide here: http://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/auto-layout-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not difficult to achieve by using auto layout on Xcode.

If you do not wish the box showing the question to change its ratio, i suggest that you put "question 1 of 7 in total etc." in a seperate UIView and set the aspect ratio on that UIView.

[image]

It's relative position should also be specified. Note that you can contain its X, or Y position as a percentage of the screen.

[image]

For the text, you can use a label, and constrain it next to the box.

The options can be space equally through the multiplier of constraints.

The Back and Next button's vertical spacing can be set to the last question rather than the bottom layout guide so that it will not be floating at the bottom.

I STRONGLY suggest that you read this guide

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2
for more information. And look through the offical Apple documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/